# How to use git on huge repo (>10g without submodule) efficiently?

Tags: git, performance, bitbucket-server

My organization ( a private banking company ) use git to track sql scripts and some binary files. They use stash server from Atlassin, and I access the server with a 4g usb modem via vpn,so the internet connection is slow.  I'm not sure how big the repo is but every git operation seems painfully slow.

I have read this article [How to handle big repositories with git – Atlassian Blogs](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/)

and when I clone the repo for the first time, I used the recommended command

`git clone -n git://path/to/the_repo.git --depth 1 --branch branch_name --single-branch`

is this the most lite command to use when cloning a big repo?(If I already know the branch and files I want to modify) I tried this command with qt 4.8 repo on github, the full size is 633mb, and after clone the .git folder is 164mb

how about other commands ?
`git status, git add, git commit` all take at least 30 seconds to 1 minute to complete, how can I speed up them? Thanks !

Comment: there are tricks / optimizations to speed them up, but I claim that git is just not the optimal tool to use if you have a big repo, especially with binary files. I would use some other tool.If you want to use git still, the next thing might worth a look is to check out some of the extensions to git that deal with large binary files, such as git-annex. If you can't use any extensions, you need to detail the operations that are slow on *your* repository, not just arbitrary big one, as well as file system, operating system and configurations used. You'll also need to describe your repo in detail.

Comment: (and git version used, and possibility to use submodules/subtrees)

Comment: There are two separate things here: The first is your connection speed, which is only relevant for the initial clone and maybe later for pulling changes. If 'status', 'add' and other local operations are slow, this is a local problem, which has nothing to do with network connections. Git has to scan the disk for a 'status' command, so if the number of files is high, this takes some time, especially on Windows. In this case I can recommend using Linux, as it is much faster, when it comes to handling thousands of files.